# Removing celery tasks by name (with wildcard?)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

Is there a way I can remove a specific set of tasks from Celery? Maybe using a wildcard? Something like:

```
app.control.delete("foobar-only-*")
```

I know I can delete all tasks with

```
from proj.celery import app
app.control.purge()
```

which comes from [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/b2668607c909c61becd151905b4525190c19ff4a/celery/bin/purge.py), but that's not very helpful as it doesn't seem that I can use that code to tweak it and do what I want.

Comment: probably depends on the backend as this would be specific to that since I do not believe there is any way but `purge`

Comment: You can terminate task if you know task_id by `app.control.revoke(task_id, terminate=True)` Didn't it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to my own question. This is an extract from the code with which I achieved my goal:

```
def stop_crawler(crawler_name):
    crawler = Crawler.objects.get(name=crawler_name)
    if crawler is None:
        logger.error(f"Can't find a crawler named {crawler_name}")
        return

    i = app.control.inspect()

    queue_name = f"collect_urls_{crawler_name}"

    # Iterate over all workers, and the queues of each worker, and stop workers
    # from consuming from the queue that belongs to the crawler we're stopping
    for worker_name, worker_queues in i.active_queues().items():
        for queue in worker_queues:
            if queue["name"] == queue_name:
                app.control.cancel_consumer(queue_name, reply=True)

    # Iterate over the different types of tasks and stop the ones that belong
    # to the crawler we're stopping
    for queue in [i.active, i.scheduled, i.reserved]:
        for worker_name, worker_tasks in queue().items():
            for task in worker_tasks:
                args = ast.literal_eval(task["args"])
                if "collect_urls" in task["name"] and args[0] == crawler_name:
                    app.control.revoke(task["id"], terminate=True)
```